# Is there an openapi description for the Autodesk Forge API?

Tags: api, autodesk-forge, power-automate

For creating a new connector for MSFT Power automate, I would like to create a new API in Azure. Is there any openAPI definition for Forge available, be it official or not?

See https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/documentation for details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autodesk publishes on swaggerHub:

https://app.swaggerhub.com/search?owner=autodesk

Comment: the link is no longer work. Did they move the definition somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no OpenAPI definition for the Forge Platform available.